# Deployment of Springboot application from AWS Java 8 to Corretto 8 plartform

Tags: corretto

Do we need any application level changes for move from AWS Java 8 platform to Corretto 8 in Elasticbeanstalk ? Since, they both are OpenJDK application specific changes should not be there correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Correct, Corretto 8 is a drop in replacement for OpenJDK 8.  If you run into issues please submit a GitHub issue:  https://github.com/corretto/corretto-8/issues and someone from my team will help.